# Passing parameters to a package from command prompt

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, dtexec

I have a ssis package `"pkg1"` with a variable `"var1"` which I pass a parameter to it from the command prompt such as

```
dtexec.exe /f c:\pkg1.dtsx /set \Package.Variables[User::var1].Properties[Value];"test"
```

In the packages I have a script task which I display the value of the variable

```
  MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::var1"].Value.ToString());
```

When I run this package from the command prompt. The messagebox opens but no value for my variable is displayed.

Comment: Thanks Hadi, it worked. I was missing the double quotes around the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to pass a string value which need to be double quoted, you have to add `\"` at the beginning and the end of value

```
dtexec.exe /f c:\pkg1.dtsx /set "\Package.Variables[User::var1].Value";\""test"\"
```